# Counting duplicates

Tags: javascript, duplicates, iteration

the function below should count the number of letters in string (text) that occur more than once, i do not get why it does not work properly.

```js
function duplicateCount(text){
  text.toUpperCase();
  var counter = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
      for (b = 0; b < text.length; b++){
        if(text[b] === text[i] && b !== i && counter.indexOf(text[b] === -1)) {
          counter += text[b];
        
      }
    }
  }
  return counter.length;
```

Comment: Not work properly as in what way? What are you trying to achieve? Get the total count of duplicates for every character, or get the number of duplicates per character?

Comment: replace `if(text[b] === text[i] && b !== i && counter.indexOf(text[b] === -1))` with ` if(text[b] === text[i] && b !== i && counter.indexOf(text[b]) === -1)`

Comment: I am trying to get the number of characters that are not unique, and the mistake was in wrong ")" as you said

Answer (score 1):

replace `if(text[b] === text[i] && b !== i && counter.indexOf(text[b] === -1))` with `if(text[b] === text[i] && b !== i && counter.indexOf(text[b]) === -1)`

Answer (score 0):

duplicates are a,b,c,d,f = 5

```js
function duplicateCount(text){
  text = text.toUpperCase('');
  var text_arr = [];
  var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        var char = text.substring(i, 1);
        if(text_arr.indexOf(text[i]) == -1) {
            text_arr.push(text[i]);
        } else {
            total++;
        }
    }
  return total;
  }

console.log('Total duplicate characters are: '+duplicateCount('aabbccddeff'));
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
function duplicateCount(text){
counterString = ""
for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
 if(text.indexOf(text[i], i+1) != -1) {
  counterString = counterString + text[i]
 }
}

alert(counterString.length);
}
```

an easy solution

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer by Krishna Kishore Andhavarapu,
the second line of your code should be replaced by

```
var text = text.toUpperCase();
```